# What details are erased when using find my phone?

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone

If I erase my phone through iCloud find my phone, Will it erase contacts and pictures?

Answer (score 1):

Everything on the device is deleted, synonymous with erasing all content and settings from Settings. All the data, including contacts and photos, are deleted from the device.